# Как получить доступ к данным POST запроса, в приложении Python3, запускаемом Gunicorn, без использования фреймворков типа Flask и Django

Tags: python-3.x, post, веб-сервер, gunicorn

Настроен сервер Nginx + Gunicorn. Gunicorn запускает файл Python приложения. Доступ к заголовкам, параметрам GET запроса есть через переменную environ. Не могу понять как получить доступ к параметрам полученным в теле POST запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Доступ к значениям параметров POST запроса можно получить из environ с помощью модуля cgi:

```
import cgi

post_env = environ.copy()
    post_env['QUERY_STRING'] = ''
    post = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=environ['wsgi.input'],
        environ=post_env,
        keep_blank_values=True
    )
post_value = post.getvalue('post_param')  # post_param это имя вашего  параметра
```